# Cross Platform for Mobile Apps

Tags: cross-platform, hybrid-mobile-app, platform

i'm going into a real big project for building cross platform mobile application.
and i want to know what **IDE** should i use or what **platform**. and i would prefer if i could use a platform using html,css and js cause i have some experience in them. but if the platform doesn't support them it's okay if it's a **VERY GOOD** one

Main Features of the App:

- it will have a chat feature(Messaging).

  -Notification Center (Notifications for friend requests,updating statuses..etc)

  - Viewing categories for a certain place with its members and activities in this place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into using PhoneGap. all you will need to know is Html, CSS and JQuery for a start. 
All this techonology  requires for you to do is write one set of code which you will be able to convert to multiple platforms (iOs, Android, Windows etc), no need to write independent codes for each.

Comment: so andrew, i write html,css and js or jquery for my mobile application and it converts it to all the platforms. one more question i'm sorry how about the community for phone gap , large community answering questions, or not ?

Comment: Yes that's correct. And they have a pretty decent size community. You can get alot of help from here also, and they have very good articles which explains in detail how to accomplish what you need.